# How to add example value for body in swagger 2.0 / OPENAPI 3?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am following the [Swagger 2.0 Annotation docs](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#requestbody) , but I am unable to add example values for body.

```
public Response updateUserInfo(@RequestBody(description = "", required = true, content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json")}) final String userInfo)
```

Is there any equivalent of `@ApiImplicitParams` or `@ExampleProperty` for body.

Though the above doc states an example for `@ApiResponse` :

```
examples = { @ExampleObject(name = "boo", value = "example",summary = "example of boo", externalValue = "example of external value") }
```

but this is not working for body.

I have also tried this but the example does not show up:

```
public Response updateUserInfo(@@Parameter(examples = {@ExampleObject(name = "userInfo", value = "some example")})) final String userInfo)
```

Comment: You can use @ApiOperation annotation and use the response property to provide the class for your response payload

Comment: @greenPadawan i am using  swagger 2.x. annotation u mentioned is in 1.x

Comment: In the link for the swagger documentation, there's the Operation annotation which basically does a similar job. FYI, I am using swagger 2.8.0 for my project and, and ApiOperation works in it

Comment: @greenPadawan thanks. In your first comment you mentioned to use response property. I am looking to add example in request body.